# rails, cancancan and certain items not recognizing permissions in production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

So I have a model, `Lodge`, and I have two levels of access that are misbehaving, but only in production (which makes debugging this a bear), and only on certain instances of `Lodge`. With a fresh DB dump this does NOT occur on my local machine while running in the production environment.

On the `super_admin` role, there are a handful of the 887 entities that return "Not authorized" and when I try to load the url directly, I get a 404 error.

Here is an example lodge that exhibits the issue:

```
2.4.0 :083 > @l = Lodge.find_by_combined('246B')
  Lodge Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "lodges".* FROM "lodges" WHERE "lodges"."combined" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["combined", "246B"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   => #<Lodge id: 444, name: "Apachedotte", lodge_number: "246", designator: "B", combined: "246B", insignia: "Tree", chartered_on: nil, url: nil, status: "Superceded 1955", created_at: "2017-01-15 21:02:49", updated_at: "2017-04-29 10:33:51", council_id: nil, slug: "246b-apachedotte", name_translation: nil, membership: nil, membership_year: nil, membership_details: nil, featured_issue_id: nil, no_known_issues: nil, renumbered_on: nil, renumbering_detail: nil, facebook_url: nil, pronunciation: nil, instagram_url: nil, twitter_url: nil, phonetic_spelling: nil, history: nil, notes: nil>
```

All the lodges that exhibit the behavior (save one) have "46" in their `lodge_number` value. The outlier is 168B (but not 168A, funny enough). the two lodges with JUST 46 (e.g. not 46x or x46) do NOT exhibit this behavior.

Super admin privs:

```
Canard::Abilities.for(:super_admin) do
  can :manage, :all
end
```

Admin privs:

```
Canard::Abilities.for(:admin) do
  includes_abilities_of :user
  can :manage, Annotation
  can :manage, BorderType
  can :manage, Council
  can :manage, IssueSet
  can :manage, Issue
  can :manage, Lodge, editorships: { editor: user  }
  can :manage, Manufacturer
end
```

Non super_user roles are authenticated by an `editorships` model, but since this persists on the same instances at a level where that is bypassed, it seems to be something else.

Editorships are a has_many :through relationship between user (as editor) and lodge. We did the through setup to allow for more granular access on each editorship in the future.

Initially there was a 404 error, but that was fixed by removing any editorships where editor_id was nil.

And a list of entities (lodge number + designator, or combined value) that are exhibiting this:

```
146A
168B
246A
246B
246C
246D
346A
346B
446A
460A
461A
462A
463A
464A
465A
466A
467A
467B
468A
469A
546A
```

- Ruby 2.4
- Rails 5.1.2
- PostgreSQL 9.6
- Centos 6.x for production, macOS
  for development